# How to efficiently create multiple APIs in Azure API Management from a single ASP.NET Web API Project?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-api-management

In Azure API Management (APIM), I currently have a single API with hundreds of [operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-key-concepts#a-nameapis-aapis-and-operations) which is backed by a monolithic ASP.NET Web API application (v5.2.3).  Essentially, I want to expose subsets of operations to different groups of developers.

For example, given an API with three operations (A, B, & C), I want Team1 to have access to all operations and Team2 to only have access to operation A.

Questions:

1. Does APIM have a built-in access control mechanism for visibility of operations?
2. If APIM does not have access control for operations, should I utilize multiple APIs for this grouping?
3. If I need to setup multiple APIs to do this, what is an elegant way can I do this from a single ASP.NET Web API project?

   - Some possible approaches include...

     - Generate multiple Swagger documents

       - In this case, it is highly involved as [generating multiple Swagger documents is not explicitly supported in Swashbuckle with ASP.NET Web API v5.3.2](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/703#issuecomment-329275628) (although it is [supported in ASP.NET Core](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#generate-multiple-swagger-documents)).

         - The author of Swashbuckle suggested [two possible workarounds](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/764#issuecomment-233506523):

           - Utilize MultipleApiVersions, as a sort of hack.
           - Split the full Swagger with post-processing.
     - Split the monolithic Web API project into multiple projects (which I have seen suggested in [a MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/09582138-a1c3-418b-b14a-d48023a53ee0/swagger-subset-and-apim-automation?forum=azureapimgmt) and in a [Swashbuckle issue 764](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/764#issuecomment-234716655), but this seems like overkill to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. APIM has visibility control at the scope of products: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-create-groups.
2. Since it is only at the scope of products, it will require you to create multiple APIs (in APIM only) and put them into separate products. Each of those APIs may point to the same endpoint just have different operations defined.
3. Multiple swagger documents would be the easiest way if you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question and answer, but I didn't find what I was looking for when I searched for this, so here goes my findings:

API Management has support for Access Groups. A product can set an access group under access control. This will make it so only users that are members of this group can see it in ApiManagement. Doing this, you can create just a single subscription for all API's, and filter using access policies, to verify that you can only use the API's that you are allowed to, due to the access groups.

I used the following policy on my API's to make sure the user has access, together with an AllApis subscription:

```
 <choose>
        <when condition="@(context?.User?.Groups == null || !(context.User.Groups.Any(q => q.Id == context?.Api?.Id)))">
            <return-response>
                <set-status code="401" reason="Unauthorized" />
                <set-header name="WWW-Authenticate" exists-action="override">
                    <value>Unauthorized. Subscription key not valid for this API."</value>
                </set-header>
            </return-response>
        </when>
    </choose>
```

All in all, this ends up with customizable access to API's, using only a single subscription key. You can choose any permutation of users and API accesses.